# MQQueue get call fails to get the message from queue

Tags: ibm-mq

MQQueue get call fails to retrieve the message from the queue with 2033 (07F1) (RC2033): MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE error. I am using the following code to get the message from the queue:

**GET message:**

```
    byte[] replyMessageBytes = null;
    try {
        this.replyConnection.open();

        MQQueue replyQueue = this.replyConnection.getQueue(CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF);
        if (null == replyQueue) {
            logger.error("Could not create reply queue.");
            throw new PFMCommunicationException("Could not create reply queue.");
        }

        MQMessage replyMessage = new MQMessage();
        MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
        gmo.resolvedQueueName = replyQueue.getResolvedQName();
        if (timeout.length > 0) {
            try {
                gmo.waitInterval = Integer.valueOf("" + timeout[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        } else {
            gmo.waitInterval = MQConstants.MQWI_UNLIMITED;
        }
        gmo.options = MQConstants.MQGMO_WAIT;
        if (null != correlationId) {
            gmo.matchOptions = MQConstants.MQMO_MATCH_MSG_ID | MQConstants.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
            replyMessage.messageId = correlationId.getBytes();
            replyMessage.correlationId = correlationId.getBytes();
        } else {
            gmo.matchOptions = MQConstants.MQMO_NONE;
            replyMessage.messageId = MQConstants.MQMI_NONE;
            replyMessage.correlationId = MQConstants.MQCI_NONE;
        }

        try {
            replyQueue.get(replyMessage, gmo);
            int length = replyMessage.getMessageLength();
            replyMessageBytes = replyMessage.readStringOfByteLength(length).getBytes();
        } catch (MQException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR on receiving reply: CC=" + e.completionCode + " RC=" + e.reasonCode + " "
                    + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR on receiving reply.", e);
        }

        if (null == replyMessageBytes) {
            logger.error("No reply received.");
        } else {
            logger.debug("Received message: " + new String(replyMessageBytes));
        }
    } catch (MQException e) {
        logger.error("ERROR:", e);
        throw new PFMCommunicationException(e);
    } catch (PFMConnectionException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new PFMCommunicationException(e);
    } finally {
        this.replyConnection.close();
        logger.debug("Closed connection with MQ replies.");
    }
```

I confirm that the message is present in the queue before the waitInterval expires and the correlationId also matches. In-fact, when I run the code without trying to match the correlationId, I am able to get the message. I guess this means either something is wrong with the response message or I am making a mistake creating the matchOptions properly.

```
    gmo.matchOptions = MQConstants.MQMO_NONE;
    replyMessage.messageId = MQConstants.MQMI_NONE;
    replyMessage.correlationId = MQConstants.MQCI_NONE;
```

This is what my response message header looks like:

```
   <Header Origin="DISPUTE1" Addressee="PSXDX2" Date="20180802" Time="123055" Area="QUERY" Content="RAddr" ID="8af3257cf01a4842bf5eec8d" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="cms/customerAccountDetails.xsd">
```

I tried with putting CorrelId instead of ID in the response header but it's still the same. Can someone please help me to find the issue?

Comment: Did you mean to ask for a message that has a message id with the same value as the correlation id?

Comment: @MoragHughson what I want is to get the message that matches the messageId or correlationId. I added a comment in Roger's answer to provide the scenario how I am testing the functionality.

Comment: Normally you would get by one or the other not both.   The normal case is the reply will have the origonal request msgid populated in the correlationid.  The reply message msgid would be new and unique not related to the request message.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (null != correlationId) {
  gmo.matchOptions = MQConstants.MQMO_MATCH_MSG_ID | MQConstants.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
  replyMessage.messageId = correlationId.getBytes();
  replyMessage.correlationId = correlationId.getBytes();
}
```

Well, that's your problem.  It would be extremely rare, if ever, that an MQ message would have the same value in BOTH the MsgId and CorrelId fields.

If you are getting a reply message for a request that you sent, and you saved the ***request message's MsgId*** after the MQPUT, then the code should be:

```
if (null != correlationId) {
  gmo.matchOptions = MQConstants.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
  replyMessage.correlationId = correlationId.getBytes();
}
```

Note: You don't save the request (outbound) message's CorrelId but rather the MsgId.  The server processing your request, should put the incoming MsgId in the reply message's CorrelId.  Hence, that is why you ONLY match on CorrelId for the reply message.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it's still the same. Let me give you the scenario how I am testing the functionality. The reply message comes from third party. As I don't have any dummy implementation for that, I do the following:

I run the application in debug mode. Execute the put message section, prepare the reply message by copying the correlationId in the ID attributed of the header, put it manually in the reply queue and run the get message section.

I guess how I am putting the message is wrong. How do I put the MsgId or CorrelId in the reply message when I put it manually?

Comment: Where is your code that shows putting the message to the queue and then saving the MsgId as a byte array i.e. byte[]

Comment: I found the problem. We have a interceptor that intercepts the incoming message from a queue and forwards the message into the queue where application is connected to. We need this because not all the messages are meant for us. So the interceptor makes sure that we read only those messages that are for us and puts the ID value into the correlation ID. There was one check that was failing and because of that the correlation ID was replacing with empty string.